# Read weight from a weighing scale and update the UI

Tags: vb.net, winforms, serial-port

I'm facing a big problem here, I'm developing a app to read data from a Weight.
Everything is working perfectly, but the result is not what I expected: when reading the data from the scale, it keeps printing the data without stopping and I would like it to read a single line and whenever there is any change in the scale, just change the value and not add a new line...

The way it's printed:

[image: What is printing]

My code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Q As Queue(Of String) = New Queue(Of String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each s In System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(s)
        Next s
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
                MsgBox("Please select a port")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
                SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
                SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
                SerialPort1.PortName = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
                SerialPort1.Open()
                Timer1.Start()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
        Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Q.Enqueue(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        SyncLock Q
            While Q.Count > 0
                TextBox1.Text &= Q.Dequeue
            End While
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, but do you actually need a queue? You could just post the new value to the UI Thread, store the last read, compare with the new one and update the TextBox only when the two don't match. So you can also remove the Timer.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the idea, I'll read more about the ConcurrentQueue and try to implement it...

Comment: Yes, but - as mentioned - do you need a queue? You can just post to a delegate in the UI Thread to update a Control when the new value is different from the last. No need for Timers, just update when actually needed. -- If you have to store the history of changes, you need another type of concurrent collection (still storing a value only when it actually changes - plus a timestamp, eventually).

Comment: No, I don't. But it's the only way that I know. Can you provide an example?

Comment: An example of what? Assigning a value to a variable? Comparing a value to that variable? Do you really need examples of those things.? Put some thought into the logic instead of asking for code to blindly copy and paste. How would you do it if it was a manual process? That will be the same logic that your code needs to implement, so you work out the logic first, which is not a programming problem, and then you work out the code to implement it.

Comment: Of how to implement the Delegate in the UI Thread to update the control when the value updates

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example using `Control.BeginInvoke()` to set a Control's property with some data coming from a secondary Thread.
You can use this method since you have all your code in a Form and you use
a SerialPort Component.

Otherwise, build a class to handle the SerialPort and pass a delegate to its Constructor, capture [SynchronizationContext.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) and [Post()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post) to the delegate.
Or use an [IProgress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) delegate (`Progress(Of String)` here) and pass this delegate to the class, then just call its [Report()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1.report) method from the event handler.

Assuming `ReadExisting()` works for you and the Encoding is set correctly (it appears to be, from the results shown in the OP), you could change the code in the DataReceived handler to:

It's required to check whether the handles of the Controls involved (the Form, mainly) are created before calling `Invoke()` / `BeginInvoke()`, otherwise you may (will, at some point) get an exception that may kill the application (the `IProgress<T>` pattern is preferable).

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim comPort = DirectCast(sender, SerialPort)
    UpdateUI(comPort.ReadExisting())
End Sub

' [...]

Private lastWeight As String = String.Empty

Private Sub UpdateUI(weight As String)
    If IsHandleCreated Then
        BeginInvoke(New Action(
            Sub()
                If Not lastWeight.Equals(weight) Then
                    lastWeight = weight
                    If TextBox1.IsHandleCreated Then TextBox1.Text = lastWeight
                End If
            End Sub))
    End If
End Sub
```

Make a test with a threaded Timer, setting the Interval to a low value (e.g., `50ms`).
You can also try to close the Form without stopping the Timer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the soluction:

```
    Public Class Form5

    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal data As String)

    Private Delegate Sub UpdateLabelDelegate(theText As String)
    Private Sub UpdateLabel(theText As String)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New UpdateLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateLabel), theText)
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = theText
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Dim returnStr As String
        returnStr = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()

                           UpdateLabel(returnStr)
                       End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SerialPort1.Open()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You cannot do that. When the handle is not created, `Me.BeginInvoke()` alone will throw. Also, you don't need `BeginInvoke()` + `InvokeRequired` / `Invoke()` elsewhere. Pick one or the other. + `InvokeRequired` may not consider the disposed state of the Control you're invoking, you may end up with an app that just, *sometimes*, closes. -- See the notes I've posted and possibly use a custom class to handle a [SerialPort class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport) object + an `IProgress<T>` delegate for the updates, not a Component dropped on a Form.